# How to deduplicate Rust functions accepting different structs with common properties?

Tags: generics, struct, rust

I have a couple of structs (`StructX` and `StructY`), and another struct that has all the common reference properties of the previous ones (`StructCommon`).

I also have a function for each of `StructX` and `StructY` that returns a `StructCommon`, but my issue is that I had to write two functions for it.

```rs
pub struct StructX<'a> {
    a: &'a str,
    b: &'a str,
    x: &'a str,
}

pub struct StructY<'a> {
    a: &'a str,
    b: &'a str,
    y: &'a str,
}

pub struct StructCommon<'a> {
    a: &'a str,
    b: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> StructCommon<'a> {
    pub fn from_x<T>(serialized: &StructX) -> StructCommon<'a>
    {
        StructCommon {
            a: serialized.a,
            b: serialized.b,
        }
    }

    pub fn from_y<T>(serialized: &StructY) -> StructCommon<'a>
    {
        StructCommon {
            a: serialized.a,
            b: serialized.b,
        }
    }

    // Pseudo-Rust proposed solution example:
    // pub fn from_either<T>(serialized: &StructX | &StructY) -> StructCommon<'a>
    // {
    //     StructCommon {
    //         a: serialized.a,
    //         b: serialized.b,
    //     }
    // }
}
```

**How can I** - if possible - **deduplicate the `from_x()` and `from_y()` methods** so I would only have to write the logic for extracting the common properties only once**?**

I have written an imaginary pseudo-code solution example method commented out called `from_either()`.

Comment: you would need to use at least one trait that represent having a specific property, that say without have real use case it's hard to advice what to do, my simple advice would be keep it simple let it be that way.

Answer (score 3):

There is another answer focusing on your specific question, but I propose an alternative solution of having `StructX` and `StructY` containing a `StructCommon` instead of having fields that happen to have the same name and type as those in `StructCommmon`. This reduces the boilerplate of converting by just returning the internal structure:

```
pub struct StructX<'a> {
    common: StructCommon<'a>,
    x: &'a str,
}

pub struct StructCommon<'a> {
    a: &'a str,
    b: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Into<StructCommon<'a>> for StructX<'a> {
    fn into(self) -> StructCommon<'a> {
        self.common
    }
}
```

This is still some boilerplate, but much less and doesn't need to change when you change the common fields.

Comment: This is a cool idea. Though in my (or rather the open source project's) real code it's really important that StructX and StructY not change, because they get serialized as-is in other code parts, and the serialization format can't change due to backwards compatibility.

Comment: @AttilaSzeremi If using `serde`, that can be done using [`#[serde(flatten)]`](https://serde.rs/attr-flatten.html).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can directly express what you want using generics in Rust unless you write a trait with methods like `get_a()` and `get_b()` and use that for your generic implementation of `from_either()`. That really doesn't reduce your boilerplate though.

However, [procedural macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html) looks like a good fit for what you're trying to do. For example, you could create a derive macro that implements `Into<StructCommon>` for `StructX` and `StructY`, and the macro can write the boilerplate code for you.

Comment: Writing a procedural macro is not trivial, it may not be worth it. But it is the only way to "generically" express the concept that `StructX.a` maps to `StructCommon.a` just because these two fields have the same name. Fields having the same name means nothing at the language level.